# How to make array of arrays in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an array like `['a','b','c','d','e','f']`. How can i convert it to an array of arrays such that `[['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f']]`

I have tried appending it normally but it give some random result

```
inputArr = input.split(',')
i=0
Yy = []
while i < len(inputArr):
    temp = [inputArr[i], inputArr[i+1]]
    Yy.append(temp)
    i += 2
```

Output : [ 'a', 'b,c', 'd,e', 'f' ]

Comment: it works as expected, `print(Yy)` gives `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]`

Comment: you code works fine, are u printing `inputArr` and not `Yy`?

Comment: I am taking the input array from sys.argv[1]. I am figuring out if there is an issue with that. I logged the input array from sys.argv[1], It was fine

Answer (score 2):

I tried your code and got no error. However, if you did, you can try this way:

```py
new_list = [lst[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(lst), 2)]
```

This outputs: `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]`, using list comprehension, which I suppose is what you want.

If you wanted an output of `[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]`, then change the `i:i+2` to `i:i+3` and change `(0, len(lst), 2)` at the end to `(0, len(lst), 3)`.

Answer (score 1):

use can use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

a = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
n = np.array(a)
print(n.reshape(3,2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `range` wich takes `(start, stop, step)`

```
lst = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
new_lst = []
for i in range(0,len(lst), 2):
    new_lst.append(lst[i:i+2])
print(new_lst)
```

notice that we step twice and slice the `list` with 2 futher index positions.
output: `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]`